# 500 Ошибка после кроссдоменного POST запроса

Tags: php, laravel, angular2, xmlhttprequest, cors

На локалке на бекэнде стоит laravel 5.2 (домен http://api.angular.ng/), в .htaccess файле прописал:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"
```

На фронте стоит angular2. POST-ом передаю запрос на бекэнд с хедерами:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

В итоге получаю 500 ошибку:

General:

```
Request URL:http://api.angular.ng/register
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 04 Jan 2017 08:18:23 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/5.6.27
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkNZbFhUVkZjVU9pYmR2RjAxQXNpcUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNUFnYTU1TkhRXC9HNTZWbXAwOHpPNE0xYzNxcjloTnlZUnNyM0NZTmN3Y0hUY3czTlwvdXJWT1pIZnNIUGpFVEJUNHA2SlZyYktYT3VPUERJVERkQkJhQT09IiwibWFjIjoiOGFmMzRmMjY2ZWQzMDhlNjc2MDQwYzQ4NTAxM2I3Mjg3MWMzYWJhZDQzM2I5M2JiZTY3NDE1ZmZkYWU1MDAwNSJ9; expires=Wed, 04-Jan-2017 10:18:23 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.27
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:application/json
Host:api.angular.ng
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/login
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто встречался с подобным?

Comment: А описание ошибки какое ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow POST http://api.angular.ng/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обычно делаю такое middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $domains = [];
        if (isset($request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            $origin = $request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

            if (in_array($origin, $domains)) {
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$origin);
            }

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

И нужно еще вставить сюда: App\Http\Kernal.php;

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
]
```

А использовать так:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('cors');
```

Comment: ну тут по сути в middleware просто делается то, что у меня в .htaccess. я так тоже делал, добавил в роуты группу, но почему-то ларавел не отдал эти хедеры. поэтому сделал через .htaccess

Comment: Так а ты middleware подключил к маршруту ? Смотри поправил, пример  подключения

Comment: конечно добавлял. в Kernel.php в $routeMiddleware добавил строку 'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class. Потом в роутах создал группу Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () { ... })

Comment: правда роут немного не так у меня прописан. попробую сделать как у тебя

Comment: @Dzedzik  Так ну а ошибка что у тебя 500 (Internal Server Error)  это хорошо а описание есть ? там может у тебя проблема вообще с синтаксисом где то ? к другим маршрутам ты сейчас нормально обращаешься ? только когда сюда ошибка?

Comment: с остальным все хорошо. идентичный GET запрос работет с фронта на бек

Comment: @Dzedzik Так ну а ты ключ передаешь ? API токен ? Может тебя раньше другое middleware отсекает ? Очисти сейчас свой лог и скинь ошикбу которая в него пишется

Comment: таки да. говорит, что токена нет: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67, но я его передаю, причем проверил - он верный передается. Request Payload {"_token":"E3uo5ISRzJoNs551nkgoMZ4e1TdIPzMaTZsHnnC2"}

Comment: @Dzedzik ААА ну вот с этого и нужно было начинать ! а ты пиши маршруты в api.php а не в web.php и используй ключ для авторизации, или тогда тебе нужно передавать csrf ключ

Comment: понял уже куда копать. вопрос наверное закрываю, дальше уже не теме будет. спасибо большое за подсказки